# Updating a config file adds additional config sections

Tags: c#, .net, config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

My goal is to programatically update a .config file belonging to another application.

I start off with a simple config file that looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test1" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I then run my code to update the connection string named `Test1` and rename it to `Test2`...

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = @"test\app.config" };
var externalConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

externalConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[1].Name = "Test2";
externalConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal, true);
```

This saves the configuration file, but now looking at the file you will see some other data has been added to it...

**ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test2" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <webControls clientScriptsLocation="/aspnet_client/{0}/{1}/" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified**

Using the Modified setting I get even more "stuff"...

```
    <configuration>
      <appSettings />
      <configProtectedData />
      <system.diagnostics />
      <system.windows.forms />
      <uri />
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test2" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.net>
        <authenticationModules />
        <connectionManagement />
        <defaultProxy />
...snip...
```

What is this data and where has it come from? More importantly how can I stop it from being written into my file?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ConfigurationSaveMode from

```
ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal
```

to

```
ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified
```

Modified only saves the properties that you have changed.

From MSDN:

Full
Causes all properties to be written to the configuration file. This is useful mostly for creating information configuration files or moving configuration values from one machine to another.

Minimal
Causes only properties that differ from inherited values to be written to the configuration file.

Modified
Causes only modified properties to be written to the configuration file, even when the value is the same as the inherited value.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help I'm afraid. I have updated the question with an example of the file output when Modified is selected.

Comment: Where is the configuration file saved? Does it overwrite the configuration your specified i.e. test\app.config or does it create a config file in the your application root?

Comment: test\app.config is the target file and the application loads data from this file and overwrites it on save.

Comment: These extra settings are probably coming from your machine.config file, since config files inherit from machine.config. I'm not sure if you can prevent the extra data from saving. An alternative would be to read the config like you would read any other xml file and modify the values as needed.

Comment: They are not adding too much noise so will probably leave them for now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this was to set the Machine Configuration File to be the same as my EXE Configuration file, this way the .net Configuration object does not see that there is any difference between Machine and EXE when it is saving.

For example:

```
var fm = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fm.MachineConfigFilename = fm.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\dude.config";
var c = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fm, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Do Stuff

c.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal, true);
```

This way you should not get the  section in your config file upon save.